# Connection closed before full header was recieved error in graphql_flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, github-issues

I'm encountering an intermittent issue while fetching data from a GraphQL endpoint using the `graphql_flutter` package in my `Flutter` app. Occasionally, I receive the error message "Connection closed before full header was received", while at other times, the requests succeed without any problems.

Here are the logs for more context:

```
flutter: OperationException(linkException: ServerException(originalException: Connection closed before full header was received, originalStackTrace: #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:96:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      HttpLink._executeRequest (package:gql_http_link/src/link.dart:131:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      HttpLink.request (package:gql_http_link/src/link.dart:76:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:656:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
, parsedResponse: null), graphqlErrors: [])
```

This error does not occur consistently but appears from time to time.

Comment: You need to share the code of your request

Comment: Do you have any idea about this error? @AizanSagheer